# On change event not being recognized?

Tags: jquery

I have this code which is looking for an onchange event:

```
//Create destination switch
    $('#regionselect').change(function(){
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
        $('.optionvalue').fadeOut(function(){
             $('.optionvalue').html(selected.html()).fadeIn()
                 .attr('class', 'optionvalue '+selected.val());   
        });
        var count = $('.countrylist').length;
        $('.countrylist').slideUp(function(){
            if(!--count) {
               $('.'+selected.val()).slideDown();
            }       
        });
    });
```

It works perfectly here:
http://jsfiddle.net/XfPv7/1/

Can anyone help?

Comment: The idea is that when a dropdown option is selected it shows the relative hidden divs within destinations.

Comment: You're not actually using the `#regionselect` element. There's a prettified drop down box (`#sarea8`) that is inserted into the document, while `#regionselect` is banished 300px to the left.

Comment: How could i get the code to run when thats changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real problem is this:

http://www.thestc.co.uk/assets/js/form.js

The scripts found here include the functions `populateSelectOptions()`, `selectMe()`, `showOptions()`, which together serve to defeat your real select onChange event handler, since you are not interacting with your real select at all.

If you kill the select replace scripts, it works fine. See: http://jfcoder.com/test/customselect.html

**EDIT**

Here's kind've a brute-force way to fix the issue.

```
function setDestOpts(dest) {
    reg = $('#regionselect');
    reg.val(dest);
    reg.trigger('change');
    $('#optionsDiv8').removeClass('optionsDivVisible').addClass('optionsDivInvisible');
}
var checkDest = function() {
    if ($('#optionsDiv8').length == 0) return;
    clearInterval(destinterval);
    c_opt = 0;
    $('#optionsDiv8 ul li a').each(function(c_opt){
        reg = $('#regionselect option');
        href = "javascript:setDestOpts('" + reg.eq(c_opt).val() + "');";
        $(this).attr('href', href);
        c_opt++;
    });
}

var destinterval = setInterval(function(){checkDest()}, 500);
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/customselect.html

All this does is change the Javascript injected into the A.HREF, which is the root problem. This simulates the changing of the value and then triggers on the onChange event.

Note, for some reason jQuery is not loading on every page load for that link on my site, so if it doesn't work the first time, reload the page after it has entirely loaded.

Comment: IS there a way to use both?  I really want to maintain the styling

Comment: Not without completely rewriting your scripts to allow different functionality.

Comment: @Andy - See my edit for a way around the issue. Note, the interval is needed because the redo needs to happen following the running of the other scripts, which occur about 3-5 seconds after page load.

Comment: does this go in the main jquery js?

Comment: @Andy - View the source of the page on my site. I put it in the header of the file, but it just needs to be included somewhere where it will run on page load.

Answer (score 1):

```
//This worked for me - I appear to have inherited similar jquery custom select code

function onChange()
{
    var el=document.getElementById("selectid");

    //el.options[] is your array of options
    if (el.options[0].selected==true)
        //Some code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle you use a `select` on the 'live' site you use some custom `select` (a div)

```
$('.outtaHere ul li a').click(function() {
 // do you stuff to show the elements
});
```

I don't know whether you can change the code of the custom select but it would be much cleaner to remove the inline javascript code.

Comment: Even if i change it to the div it won't make any difference :(

Comment: Can you perhaps setup a fiddle with the exact same code so I can fix it there?

Comment: This one actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/XfPv7/3/ So would the one @Andy posted above if the id was `#regionselect`.